# Can't set two elements at the same horizontal level

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

https://jsfiddle.net/xtm5oqjh/
When you open my modal ("+" sign on the navbar) you see that the button "save changes" and the "priority" dropdown do not have the same height and are not at the same level horizontally.

After this:

```
.input-group {
    height: 31px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It does get she same height as the Save Changes button but it's still not at the same level horizontally as the margin is still there. I'm puzzled as to why this happen. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This element:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 w-50">
  ...
</div>
```

The class `mb-3` is adding margin-bottom to that group of elements, pushing it up higher than the "Save Changes" button you are trying to line it up with. Remove that class and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks! I had missed that bit.